# Understanding monads in scala

Tags: scala, haskell, monads

I'm trying to understand what monads are (not just in scala, but by example using scala). Let's consider the most (in my opinion) simple example of a monad:

```
scala.Some
```

As some articles state, every monad in [its classic sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Monad_laws) should preserve some rules for the `flatMap` and `unit` functions.

Here is the definition from `scala.Some`

```
@inline final def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B]
```

So, understand it better I want to understand it [from the category theory standpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Introduction). So, we're considering a monad and it's supposed to be a functor (***but between what?***).

Here we have to category `Option[A]` and `Option[B]` and the `flatMap` along with the `f: A => Option[B]` passed into it is supposed to define a ***Functor*** between them. But in the tranditional category definition it's a functor from a category to itself.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The idea of a monad and what `flatMap` does is simple: a monad is a box that holds a value, and you give a function `f` to `flatMap` that does something with the value in the box, and you get back another box that contains the result of applying `f` to the value of the original box.

Comment: The category is the category of scala types, so `Option` is an endofunctor on that category.

Comment: @Lee So it maps each type `T` to `Option[T]`?

Comment: @Lee Excellent point. A little clarification about map between types. If we say that we have a map between types `T1` and `T2` it means that we have a map between all values of `T1` into some (maybe proper) subset of values of type `T2`. Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The category is the category of scala types, where the objects are types and the arrows are functions between values of those types. `Option` is an endofunctor on this category. For each object (i.e. type) in the Scala category, the `Option` type constructor maps each type `A` into a type `Option[A]`.

In addition it maps each arrow `f: A => B` into an arrow `fo: Option[A] => Option[B]` which is what `Option.map` does.

A Monad is a Functor `M` along with two operations, `unit: A => M[A]` and `join: M[M[A]] => M[A]`. For `Option`, `unit(x: A) = Some(x)` and `join` can be defined as:

```
def join[A](o: Option[Option[A]]): Option[A] = o match {
  case None => None
  case Some(i) => i
}
```

`flatMap` can then be defined as, `flatMap(f, m) = join(map(f, m))`. Alternatively the monad can be defined using `unit` and `flatMap` and `join` defined as `join(m) = flatMap(id, m)`.

Comment: In scala `join` is `flatten` (as far as I know).

Comment: Let me ask you one more question. As you said that we have two operations `join` and `unit`. In the [category monad definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Formal_definition) we also have two natural transformations. Is it the same or we can prove that our monad is a "monad" according to the category definition. I didn't do it myself and don't want the actual proof (if it's true). Just want to know if it is.

Comment: @user3663882 Yes, `join` and `unit` correspond exactly to mu and eta. Furthermore, the [laws do hold for them](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+laws.html); associativity corresponds to the diagram with T^3, and left and right identity are, IIRC, equivalent to the other one.